# understanding type hinting and namespace in php

Tags: php, namespaces, type-hinting

i don't have much intuitive knowledge on type hinting and namespaces. So i made up the following code to work with both of the concepts.I have three php pages holding three classes inside same directory.They are--

> 1.Student.php
>
> 2.Institution.php
>
> 3.enroll.php.

i want to use both the `Student and Institution` class inside the `enroll` class.I applied `namespaces` in both `Student and Institution` class.And `use` them inside enroll class.But something isn't quite right here.I am getting these errors:

> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Student' has no
>   effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\typehint\enroll.php on line 2
>
> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Institute' has no
>   effect in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\typehint\enroll.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Student' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\typehint\enroll.php on line 10

***can anyone explain what is wrong here and how i can fix this ?***

**student.php**

```
namespace Student;
 class Student{

     public $name;

     publci function __construct($value){
        $this->name=$value;
     }

 }
```

**institute.php**

```
namespace Institute;
   class Institute{

      public $institute;
      public function __construct($val){
         $this->institute=$val;
      }
   }
```

**enroll.php**

```
use Student;
use Institute;
  class enroll{

      public function __construct(Student $student,Institute $institute){
         echo $student->name.' enrolled in '.$institute->institute.' school .';
      }
  }
  $student=new Student('zami');
  $institute=new Institute('Government Laboratory High School');

  $enroll=new enroll($student,$institute);
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have to `include` the other files first. otherwise, PHP doesn't know where to look for the namespaces you are looking for.

enroll.php:

```
<?php
include "student.php";
include "institute.php";
use Student;
use Institute;
  class enroll{

      public function __construct(Student $student,Institute $institute){
         echo $student->name.' enrolled in '.$institute->institute.' school .';
      }
  }
  $student=new Student('zami');
  $institute=new Institute('GLAB');

  $enroll=new enroll($student,$institute);
```

Comment: if i include them then what is the point of using namespace ? can you clarify

Comment: include: getting physical files together into one logical script. namespace: logically seperating and sorting stuff. i don't really know how to write in a short comment what (and how) namespaces are used for, and neither do i know how to write in how many ways namespaces and includes have basically nothing in common. fact is: you still have to include the file, otherwise PHP can not process what is IN the file.

Comment: Namespaces are not files, they are mainly used to organise classes. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: You can autoload all classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php